# Why can't the static and register storage classes be used together?

Tags: c, compilation, storage-class-specifier

When defining a variable in the following manner:

```
static register int a1 = 0;
```

we get the error:

```
error: multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers
```

Is there any fundamental reason for this error? Why can't a variable be both stored in a register, and also be initialized only at start up/first call? *It is possible to attach the register storage class to a global variable.* <- edit: not true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a compiler implemented what you wanted faithfully then it would tie up a CPU register for the length of your program. That's hardly practical.

Remember that `register` is only advisory.

Comment: At first this didn't entirely make sense because I thought that a global register definition does indeed compile, however I now checked and saw that everything is consistent :)

Answer (score 7):

The standard does not allow use of more than one storage-class specifier in a declaration.

From the C99 Standard:

> **6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers**
>
> 1 *storage-class-specifier:*
>
> ```
> typedef
> extern
> static
> auto
> register
> ```
>
> 2 At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration.

Comment: In a sense this is a good answer (plus one), but it doesn't really address the *why*.

Comment: @Bathsheba, unfortunately, I don't fully grasp the justifications for this. Your answer makes sense for not allowing `static` and `register`. I don't understand the problems that might arise if we combine others.

Comment: In C11, that's no longer true as `_Thread_local` can be combined with `static` and `extern`.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Good to know. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that the **register** qualifier implies that the variable has **automatic storage duration**. It is basically an auto variable  for which you are telling the compiler that it would be good to place in a General Purpose CPU register.

**static** qualifier implies a static or thread storage duration.

Obviously the two are incompatible if applied to the same variable!

It would be like asking to have a variable that die and survive (at the same time) when the activation record it belongs is removed.

Comment: @Lundin, wrong. `register` is a storage class, not a storage duration. `register` objects have automatic storage duration.

Comment: I don't agree with your POV. Just as the `static` storage class applies to static or thread storage duration, `register` could do the same. The only real constraint that `register` implies that the `&` may not be applied to the object, so you guarantee that there is no aliasing. This could make sense with static objects. In fact, I have a proposal for C2x that implies this.

Comment: @JensGustedt Ah right, that didn't make any sense, I got caught up in terminology. What I meant to say is that both `register` and `auto` are storage-class specifiers and cannot be combined. `auto register int x;` will not compile.

Comment: @Lundin that is not a reason per se, `static` and `_Thread_local` are allowed together, `static` and `register` aren't (for now).

Comment: @JensGustedt Wouldn't it be better to let `register` rest in peace and come up with something else, for the scenario you describe? Suppose something like `static int* restrict x;` would be allowed at local scope, for the case where you wish to block aliasing. Since the purpose of the `restrict` keyword was supposedly to block aliasing in the first place.

Comment: I don't think so. Did you read my paper? In any case we should take this off line. Thanks.